# Auto selection of `Dropdownlist` not working in MVC

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to bind the dropdown with SelectListItem strongly typed. I am giving both the Text and Value as same and like string values which are coming from DB.
Below code I am trying

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => item.Name, Model.Names, "Please select", new { @id = "ddrName", @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px;" })
```

`item.Name` contains the name of the particular student/record.
I have binded the list as like below:

```
 obj.Names = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value="Rajesh", Text="Rajesh" },
                 new SelectListItem { Value ="Vishal", Text="Vishal" },
                 new SelectListItem { Value ="Sarath", Text="Sarath" },
                 new SelectListItem { Value ="Sudhir", Text="Sudhir" }
            };

public List<SelectListItem> Names { get; set; }
```

I am getting the data from database as follows.

> Rajesh
>       Vishal
>       Sarath
>       Sudhir

But I need to get the page should show the dropdowns with some selcted values.

I am getting only --Select-- by default even the value is present in list.

Can someone please help me to solve this.

Comment: Are you able to show your `Names` list values in the dropdown? I am not sure what your question is here.

Comment: Yes Rahul, I am able to show... But the default value --select-- is binding every time...
foreach (var item in Model.students)
        {
        <tr>
            
            <td>
                Html.DropDownListFor(x => item.Name, Model.Names, "Please select")
            </td>
            <td>
               Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>

        </tr>
        }

Comment: And what value are you expecting? You are initalizing a new `SelectListItem` always for you values that are coming from the database. Also is your question is that when you are posting your form, you are not getting your value in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add SelectList(Model.Names, "Value", "Text") parameter in DropDownListFor.

It you want to show "please select" then

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Name, new SelectList(Model.Names, "Value", "Text"), "Please select", new { @id = "Name", @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px;" })
```

If not want to show "Please select" then

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Name, new SelectList(Model.Names, "Value", "Text"), new { @id = "Name", @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px;" })
```

If you want to selected  "Vishal" then

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Name, new SelectList(Model.Names, "Value", "Text","Vishal"), new { @id = "Name", @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px;" })
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3x5Go2)

**UPDATE:**
Update for new dropdown asked in the comment section.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.WeeklyStatus, new SelectList(Model.WeeklyStatus, "Value", "Text", item.WeeklyStatus), new { @id = "Name"})
```

It works fine. it selects the option to depend on `item.WeeklyStatus` value.if the value does not match with the given option then by default select the first option.
[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wCdbKi)

Comment: From where item.WeeklyStatus came?

Answer (score 1):

Use These properties in razor view while displaying data
Text="Active", Value="True",Selected=true

Comment: Hi Hamza Javed,

I didn't get your suggestion.. Can u elaborate please